# How to use WrapPanel that consists of many TextBlocks under DataTrigger Setter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

I have a `DataGrid` that consists of some columns. In one `DataGridTemplateColumn`, I want to use a condition. If the condition is `False`, it should display a single bound property. If the condition is `True`, it should display multiple bound properties (that's what I can't accomplish). How can I use `WrapPanel` under `DataTrigger` `Setter`?

My XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_SipList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items3}" Margin="0 8 0 0"  CanUserSortColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8"  materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="cfgText">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter  Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="cfgText2">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter  Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="START" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_MontajStart" Checked="cb_MontajStart_Checked" Unchecked="cb_MontajStart_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding LISTE_MONTAJ_START}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LISTE_KIMLIK}" Tag="{Binding Path=LISTE_MONTAJ_START}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText2}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PRODUCT" MaxWidth="450">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding konfTanim}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding LISTE_URUN}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding konfTanim}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter>
<!--This is what I can not combine more than one textblock under Datatrigger Setter-->
                                             <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="450">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=yeni_ModelTanim}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT4}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd4}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT5}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd5}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT6}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd6}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>  
                                            </WrapPanel>   
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- ........................................................... -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="txt_Configuration"  Header="configuration" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="450">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=yeni_ModelTanim}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT4}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd4}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT5}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd5}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT6}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd6}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>  
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You can define a `DataTemplateSelector` as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=net-5.0) and then set the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector = toYourTemplateSelector`

Comment: Isn't there any other way I can do this just using XAML (without C#)?

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple different representations of the same type, depending on a flag or other properties, you have to implement a custom `DataTemplateSelector` and a data template for each representation, e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="KonfTanimFalseTemplate">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding LISTE_URUN}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="KonfTanimTrueTemplate">
   <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="450">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=yeni_ModelTanim}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT4}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd4}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT5}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd5}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT6}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd6}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
   </WrapPanel>  
</DataTemplate>
```

The data template selector checks the `konfTanim` property and returns the appropriate data template.

```
public class KonfTanimDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      if (!(container is FrameworkElement frameworkElement) || !(item is YourItemType yourItem))
         return null;

      var dataTemplateName = yourItem.konfTanim ? "KonfTanimTrueTemplate" : "KonfTanimFalseTemplate";
      return (DataTemplate) frameworkElement.FindResource(dataTemplateName);
   }
}
```

You could also pass in the template names via properties to avoid hard-coding them here. This can help to reuse the selector in your application. In your `DataGrid`, you could add the data templates to the `Resources` with an instance of the selector and use it in the template column like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemTypeList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="KonfTanimFalseTemplate">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding LISTE_URUN}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="KonfTanimTrueTemplate">
         <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="450">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=yeni_ModelTanim}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT4}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd4}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT5}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd5}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MT6}" Tag="{Binding Path=monStd6}" Style="{StaticResource cfgText}"/>
         </WrapPanel>  
      </DataTemplate>
      <local:KonfTanimDataTemplateSelector x:Key="KonfTanimDataTemplateSelector"/>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource KonfTanimDataTemplateSelector}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

> Isn't there any other way I can do this just using XAML (without C#)?

There is not really anything bad about having a data template selector for complex conditions.

- [Choosing a DataTemplate Based on Properties of the Data Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#choosing-a-datatemplate-based-on-properties-of-the-data-object)

However, often having a flag to determine the type of an object is a sign that the corresponding class should be split into two different types. In this case, you could create a data template with a specific `DataType` for both types. Unfortunately, *automatic* data template selection by type works in other items controls, but in `DataGrid` or more specifically a template column, you would have to use workarounds, which might be more cumbersome than to just create a selector that might as well be reusable in other columns.